# How to use String.Split() in EF core

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a list of names in the DB that I want to filter from a field. But it has to match the beginning of the word, not the middle.

let's say I have this in the DB:

```
"foobar"
"bar foo"
"bar fos foo"
"barfoo"
"bar basfoo"
```

if I type "foo", I should get:

```
"foobar"
"bar foo"
"bar fos foo"
```

I tried this already:

```csharp
query.Where(x => x.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.None).Any(y => y.StartsWith(name)))
```

but apparently .Split() cannot be translated to SQL.
I also cannot use a combination of .IndexOf() and .Substring(), since the names can have multiple places that should be split.

And I don't want to switch to client side evaluation for this.

Is there any way to translate Split() to SQL?

Comment: What would the equivalent SQL be?

Comment: Can you search for "starts with foo, or contains space+foo"?

Comment: Use EF.Functions.Like and combine with client side regex or simple string manipulation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not a way to translate `Split` to SQL becasue SQL does not have a standard function for splitting strings*. There are some methods to do it, but IMHO they are messy and completely unintuitive.

To solve your problem, I would pull back maybe more data than I need and do the splitting/filtering in-memory. Something like:

```
query.Where(x => x.Contains(name))
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Where(x => x.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.None).Any(y => y.StartsWith(name)))
```

That will pull any record that *contains* the name anywhere in the string, then do the splitting in memory to match the start of one of the sections.

You could be a bit more surgical by doing:

```
query.Where(x => x.StartsWith(name) || x.Contains(" " + name))
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Where(x => x.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.None).Any(y => y.StartsWith(name)))
```

But the difference in performance will depend on the size of your dataset and how many false-positives you get in the first method.

---

*SQL Server 2016 seems to have added a string_split method, but there may not be support for it in EF Core yet.