# C# & Entity Framework, compile error CS0854

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, compiler-errors, contains

I have this query in Entity Framework to SQL Server:

```
resultadoConsulta = resultadoConsulta
                        .Where(q => (typeViewId == null || listaTypeViewsIds.Contains(q.TypeViewId)) &&
                                    (textoABuscar == null || (q.Title!.ToLower().Contains(textoABuscar.Trim()) || q.Description!.ToLower().Contains(textoABuscar.Trim())
                                        || _baseContext.Tags.
                                        Where(t => t.Title!.ToLower().Contains(textoABuscar))
                                        .Select(ty => ty.Id)
                                        .Any(id =>  q.Tags.Split(';').Contains(id.ToString().ToUpper()) )    
                                        )));
```

In this piece of code `q.Tags.Split(';')` I'm getting a compile error

> CS0854: An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: _"Is there a way to get rid of this?"_ - yes, but highly likely it will be useless because EF will not be able to translate this into SQL query.

Comment: you can use below link  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73128966/how-to-use-string-split-in-ef-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use String.Split() in EF core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73128966/how-to-use-string-split-in-ef-core)